# Word for Majboor - A person who is forced to do something because of the circumstances.

Tags: single-word-requests, hindi

We use "majboor" in Hindi to describe such a person.

Google says that "helpless" means unable to defend oneself or to act without help.

Is that the word for the same or there  is something else?

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a word to describe a third person in this situation. We do have expressions that people use when they find themselves in such a situation, to excuse their behavior. I might say, "my hands are tied" to mean that I must perform my duties whether I want to or not. I also might say "I have no choice" to indicate the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Somebody in such a position might be said to be **constrained** or under **straitened** circumstances, the latter particular if operating under financial restrictions.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/constrained)  defines constrained as:

> constrained
>   [kuh n-streynd] 
>   adjective
>
> 1. forced, compelled, or obliged:
>      a constrained confession.
> 2. stiff or unnatural; uneasy or embarrassed:
>      a constrained manner.

and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/straiten) defines straiten as:

> straiten
>   [streyt-n] 
>   verb (used with object)
>
> 1. to put into difficulties, especially financial ones:
>      His obligations had straitened him.
> 2. to restrict in range, extent, amount, pecuniary means, etc:
>      Poverty straitens one's way of living.
> 3. Archaic.
>      to make narrow.
>      to confine within narrow limits.

Answer (score 1):

I have found two words for describing such a situation.

If I have to perform a task which I personally find against my will but the situation and the circumstances demand it to be performed or the law or morality demands me to do it

I would express it by saying

I was **compelled** to do so.

or

I was **obligated** to do so.

Answer (score 0):

*Predetermined, predestined* could be acceptable.